# csh: setting command completion for `cd` to show both directories and files

Tags: autocomplete, cd-command, csh

In my `csh` terminal, when I do:

`ls` <kbd>tab</kbd> -- it shows everything in the current directory as a possibility

`cd` <kbd>tab</kbd> -- it shows only directories in the current directory as a possibility. If no directories exist, in the current directory, it won't list anything

I would like to have `cd` <kbd>tab</kbd> to behave similar to `ls` <kbd>tab</kbd> and show both files & directories. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That must be `tcsh`, not `csh`. For `tcsh`, you could add this to you `~/.tcshrc`:

```
complete cd p/1/f/
```

Comment: I have two addon queries
1). I traced original 'cd' behavior to `complete cd p/1/d/`in my global/system `.cshrc`. Now is it possible to undefine this global cshrc's `complete` command instead of adding `complete cd p/1/f/` to my local cshrc?

2). Can you point to any good online resource to explore this `complete` command of csh?

Comment: @BluVio, the `tcsh` man page comes to mind. Can't help you much more, I switched from `tcsh` to `zsh` decades ago, and I tend to agree with the general opinion that there's no point using (t)csh in this day and age. Also note that tcsh has that directory completion on cd even if you don't source that global config file (unless you start it with `-f`).

Comment: Thanks. Gone through the tcsh man page and gained a little insight. `uncomplete cd` is the answer to above my question#1. BTW, strangely (for me) man page says keyword 'f' is for files but it completes both files & directories!!

Comment: @BluVio, a directory is one of many types of files. You've got _regular_ files (probably the ones you're thinking of), devices, directories, fifos, symlinks, sockets, and more depending on the system. The `f` is for that general meaning of file.